# Is it possible to use SpringSession (version 2.0.2 or later) with Spring 3.2.10?

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

We have old legacy Spring application: Spring 3.2.10, Spring Security 3.2.10. Now we need to use Spring Session with it. But when we add Spring Session in project, following exception appears during deployment:

```
2020-02-25 15:37:45,000 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 844) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."application.ear"."server.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."application.ear"."server.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
                at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
                at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
                at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
                at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:183)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:220)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:391)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
                at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
                at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
                at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
                at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
                at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
                at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
                ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider from [Module "deployment.navigator-DEV-SNAPSHOT.ear.server-DEV-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]
                at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
                at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
                at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
                at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
                ... 38 more
```

The reason of this exception is that ObjectProvidear appeared in Spring only since version 4.3. But for many reasons we can't upgrade Spring version right now. Is it possible to use Spring Session with Spring 3.2 somehow?

Here is the fragment of pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is my java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class SessionConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultCookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
        DefaultCookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
        defaultCookieSerializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID");
        return defaultCookieSerializer;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static class SessionInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: No since it has a dependency you're not willing to fulfill. You'll have to provide the same functionality through other means (i.e. write it yourself).

Comment: What are the reasons you can't upgrade Spring version?

Comment: @Boris, the reasons are company's requirements :(